# What format string do I use for milliseconds in date strings on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm required to parse strings in a format that includes milliseconds. What format string do I use to get the right date value?

For example, suppose I have a string with the following value: "2011-06-23T13:13:00.000"

What format string do I pass to my NSDateFormatter in the following code?

```
NSString *dateValue = @"2011-06-23T13:13:00.000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formatString = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.???";
[formatter setDateFormat:formatString];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateValue];
```

What do I use in place of ??? in the code above?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

It's `SSS`, per the [Unicode Locale Data Markup Language spec](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

More generally, use any number of upper-case S characters to get that many decimal places in the fractions-of-a-second component. (So `ss.S` will show the time to the nearest tenth of a second, for example.)

Comment: I was wondering if you know how I can make a lenient parsing of the milliseconds? The date might have 6, 7 or even no millisecond. I could go with regular expressions but I was wondering if this can be done out of the box with a proper format string.

Comment: This way the maximum number of S's is three, e.g. SSS. If you add more you just get zeros e.g. for the timeIntervalSince1970 of 1415986217.544384 and .SSSSSS you get .544000 so not a great solution.

Comment: @Cyupa A millisecond is only 1/1000 of a second. 6 decimal places is microseconds, and 1 decimal place is deciseconds. – Using milliseconds for any number of decimals is as wrong as using literally for something figuratively; you can still do it, but that's changing the meaning of the word.

Answer (score 7):

The [Date Format Patterns guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) suggests that "S" is the format specifier for fractions of seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass same number of 'S' at the end for example My Date was **'2015-11-17T03:36:45.041503Z'** the i used **'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz'** formatter, I mean see the number of 'S' is 6 as 6 digit coming in date.

Comment: What would be formatted to get nanoseconds in microseconds instead of milliseconds. I have tried with 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz' and 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSz' and it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

use `SSS` for three decimal places of a second

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Comment: That fails. I get no date back.