# How to get iOS date format of current date into an integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to figure out how to get the current date and time into a number up to the seconds?

I saw this post [What format string do I use for milliseconds in date strings on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456626/what-format-string-do-i-use-for-milliseconds-in-date-strings-on-iphone) but I am actually trying to get it into just a number...

EDIT: Sorry meant seconds

Comment: That's what NSDate is for. Seconds in double precision.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `NSDate`? There is a method that gives the date as a number.

Comment: @Lion789 edited answer for second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want `UTC` timestamp and want to store in `int` than on 32 bit this is not possible use instead `long long` which has larger range and can be used as integer

```
NSString *dateValue = @"2011-06-23T13:13:00.000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formatString = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
[formatter setDateFormat:formatString];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateValue];
long long dateInMillis = [date timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;  //This will give milliseconds
long dateInSeconds =  [date timeIntervalSince1970];  //This will give seconds
```

**EDIT:** For current date in `long` value use

```
//This will give seconds of current date
long dateInSeconds =  [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: Is a long considered an integer or how do I get it to be an integer value?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an `NSDate` to a `double` using:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: This should give it to me in seconds then right not milliseconds because I need it in seconds actually?

Comment: this gives seconds before comma

Comment: before comma? what do you mean by that?

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a double and it is in Seconds but the fractional part is millis

Answer (score 1):

millis:

```
long long milliseconds = llround(([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0));
```

Comment: Thanks for getting it in milliseconds but I meant seconds