# How to constuct NSDate object from String with milliseconds

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need to construct `NSDate` object from `String`, so I wrote the following code:

```
func getNSDateObjectFromString(string: String) -> NSDate { 
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    let date = formatter.dateFromString(string)
    return date!
}
```

Unfortunately, the input string sometimes may contain milliseconds too. What can I do in this case? I don't find any way to read milliseconds (not in the day) according to the http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456626/what-format-string-do-i-use-for-milliseconds-in-date-strings-on-iphone)

Comment: @Gandalf Thanks for the answer, but in this case string doesn't containing milliseconds will throw

Comment: Okkk, if situation is like "input string sometimes may contain milliseconds", then you can truncate the string with separator "." Now you can use the matching formatter depending upon the resultant array which may or may not contain the second object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the format doesn't support "optional" fields. So you have to try the formats one by one:

```
func getNSDateObjectFromString(string: String) -> NSDate {
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    var date = formatter.dateFromString(string)

    if date == nil {
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
        date = formatter.dateFromString(string)
    }

    return date!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case string doesn't containing milliseconds will throw

Answer (score 1):

#### A Swift 3 Solution

After a bit of trial and error with the date format this is what worked for me with Swift 3.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let date = formatter.date(from: "2017-03-11 13:16:31.177")!
debugPrint(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

and after a round trip results in the expected debug output of

`"2017-03-11 13:16:31.177"`

Note that using the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"` resulted in `formatter.date(from:` returning a `nil` optional `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Are they important?
In DateFormatter you create your matching string in years, months, days, hours, mins, secs, but you don't need to. If your matching string does not contain any of them, formatter will just ignore them.