# Date Formatter issue in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, date, nsdateformatter

I need to convert a date string "2015-03-10 00:00:00.000"(string from web service) to NSDate. I have used code like this

```
NSDateFormatter *fromDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fromDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];      
NSDate *outputDate = [fromDateFormat dateFromString:@"2015-03-10 00:00:00.000"];
```

outputDate is nil. I tried without last triple zeros, and it is working. but I can't remove that zeros, because it is from a service.

Comment: anyone know what is mean by lat triple zeros ?

Comment: This has the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456626/what-format-string-do-i-use-for-milliseconds-in-date-strings-on-iphone

Comment: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want convert string to date using This function

```
NSDate *current=[self convertStringToDate:data.strCreateDate formate:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Put this method in your projects

```
- (NSDate *)convertStringToDate: (NSString *)date formate:(NSString *)formate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:formate];
    return [dateFormat dateFromString:date];
}
```

This is helpfult to you..

Comment: @Arun Kumar P check your  server time, may be your time-zone and server  different.

Comment: You just makes that in a function, Actually i need to know about last triple zeros in the date string.

Comment: any idea about what is the format for last .000  ?

Comment: got the correct format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"