# How to convert Nstring to NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i want to convert nsstring to nsdate 
i have string have this value

```
08:00:00
```

i want to convert it so i wrote this code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];  
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:_startTime];
NSLog(@"%@",startDate);
```

_startTime have this value =     08:00:00

but startDate after i display it , it had this value

```
2000-01-01 06:00:00 +0000
```

Update I wrote this code

```
 NSString *dateString = _startTime;
NSDateFormatter *formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
startDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@",startDate);
```

i want the output be 08:00:00

Comment: where do you init startTime?
When I run the following code it gives me the expected result.
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:00:00"];
    NSLog(@"%@",startDate);

Comment: Please check This Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315678/date-formatter-issue-in-objc/33315709#33315709

Comment: i get it from segue but i nslog it and i works fine

Comment: NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    


    NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:00:00"];
    NSLog(@"fdhvfjfdjd%@",startDate);
keep ouptut this value 2000-01-01 06:00:00 +0000

Comment: Please refer followng url
[NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Comment: Your `NSString` to `NSDate` conversion works without problems but you are then using `NSLog` without proper `NSDate` to `NSString` conversion.

Comment: see my answer please....

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3917250/2792531).

Comment: Moreover, in order to find the *actual* question, you have to look at a comment on the check-marked answer, and to find the actual answer, you have to look in a section marked "edit" of the check-marked answer.  This is an abomination of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have NSDate without a date !
if you want to access the time from an NSDate you'll need to use NSDateComponents (or NSTimeInterval).

To access the time from your NSDate using NSDateComponents :

```
NSString *startTime = @"08:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startTime];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]);
```

I don't get what's the purpose of changing the string `_startTime`, do you want to compare dates ?

---

Edit :

```
NSString *startTime = @"08:00:00";
NSString *endTime = @"23:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startTime];
NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endTime];

NSTimeInterval difference = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

NSInteger temp = difference;

NSDate* newDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; (i < difference && [newDate compare:startDate] == NSOrderedDescending); ++i)
{

    newDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(temp - i*60*10)];

    NSLog(@"%@",newDate);

}
```

run this and use NSDateComponents to log what you want !

Comment: for example i have time =  08:00:00 start  and 23:00:00 end time  and duration 10 minute i want t display all times between them as that
08:00:00
08:10:00
08:20:00
08:30:00
08:40:00
............
22:30:00
22:40:00
22:50:00
23:00:00

Comment: do you mean _startTime = @"08:00:00 start" ?

Comment: all i want just have all these values

Comment: yes and end time 23:00:00 and interval 10 minute i want to get all times between them

Answer (score 0):

Use this code i think this one help you..

```
NSString *dateStr = @"08:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *datFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* mydate = [datFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date: %@", [datFormatter stringFromDate:mydate]);
```

i think this is what you really want...