# How to get NSTimeInterval from NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I am trying to convert following string "2016-05-15T14:40:43.447" to `NSDate` but its not `NSDateFormatter` always returns `nil`.

This is what I'm doing currently.

```
- (NSTimeInterval) timeIntervalFromDateString:(NSString *)stringDate {
    if(!stringDate || ![stringDate length]) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    static NSDateFormatter *df = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        df = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS"];
    });
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:stringDate];
    // date is always returns nil.
    return [date timeIntervalSince1970];
}
```

---

I have tried setting following formats:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssz
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss Z
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS Z
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS z
```

But none of them worked.

I have checked [What format string do I use for milliseconds in date strings on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456626/what-format-string-do-i-use-for-milliseconds-in-date-strings-on-iphone) as well, but doesn't help.

Any luck?

Comment: Why you want a dispatch_once block there? Is it needed

Comment: Yes, I have used to make sure that, `NSDateFormatter` would create only for once.

Comment: Anyway if you are creating dateformatter instance in the method, the scope of it will be in the method only. So even if you are creating each time, it will be cleared from memory when the method is exited. I think since you have given dispatch_once, the dateformatter instance is not getting allocated and is nil everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`14:40:43` is 24 hour format, that's capital H

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (NSTimeInterval) timeIntervalFromDateString:(NSString *)stringDate {
        if(!stringDate || ![stringDate length]) {
            return 0.0f;
        }
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
        NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:stringDate];

        return [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    }
```

Comment: And you need to change date format also. I have updated my answer