# Converting specific string to NSDate object in swift 2

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I have a string representing a date

`"2016-06-28T22:26:31.200577Z"`

and the dateformatter I use uses the format

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`

the extra `".200577"` is causing my dateformatter to return nil when I try convert the date string to a NSDate object.

I have tried changing my dateformatter string to

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssssZ"`

but this is not correct. I am unsure whether the `".200577"` actually denotes a fraction of a second or is something else like a time zone.. At the moment I can get past this error by splitting the end part off of the string but I do not want to lose this information.

I am looking for help as to what my correct dateformatter string should be.

Comment: Did the code work, its working at my end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the [Unicode Markup Language](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) its

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
```

Reference : SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456626/what-format-string-do-i-use-for-milliseconds-in-date-strings-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get formatted NSDate object

```
let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
 dateformatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
 dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
 print(dateformatter.dateFromString("2016-06-28T22:26:31.200577Z"))
```

// Optional(2016-06-28 22:26:31 +0000)