# How to convert "2017-07-11T06:52:15.948Z" in to like "JUL, 7 2017" in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert string to date, and again date to string.

I tried below, but it gives me a nil value error

```
let string = "2017-07-11T06:52:15.948Z"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print("EXACT_DATE : \(dateString)")
```

then I tried to use only the date without time by seperating the exact string like below

```
let string = "2017-07-11T06:52:15.948Z"
let dateonly = (string.components(separatedBy: "T"))[0]
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
dateformatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
let date = dateformatter.date(from: dateonly!)

print(date ?? "no date ")


dateformatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy" //Your New Date format as per requirement change it own
let newDate = dateformatter.string(from: date!) //pass Date here
print(newDate)
```

this works fine. but show me the wrong month

hope your help with this

Comment: You don't need to save the locale temporarily, just set it back do `Locale.current`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for reference purpose I taken the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456626/what-format-string-do-i-use-for-milliseconds-in-date-strings-on-iphone) for append the milliseconds `SSS`

just change the date format

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

for full code

```
   let string = "2017-07-11T06:52:15.948Z"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale // save locale temporarily
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy" ; //"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale --> but no need here
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print("EXACT_DATE : \(dateString)")
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. can you tell me what if string is `2017-05-31T14:00:00Z`